# "undefined reference" errors when trying to use address sanitizer with GCC

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to build my project with

```
g++ -O0 -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

but get lots of errors like:

```
/home/user/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:715: undefined reference to `__asan_report_load8'
```

How to compile project with AddressSanitize support?

My gcc version is 4.8.4.

Comment: That's not the complete compilation line, since you don't have the file name. Did you compile/link in separate steps? You also forgot to mention the version of gcc you are using...

Comment: Please, set the correct answer @yugr one since the one you marked is not really correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the switch <s>`-lasan`</s> `-fsanitize=address` to your *both* your compile *and* link command line to link the correct library.

Note: the original answer -lasan is outdated and should not be used, as per comments

Comment: This neither works on WSL nor on windows. With all versions of libasan installed.

Comment: In my experience when this is necessary gcc is installed incorrectly

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Below answer from @yugr is correct. Just adding this comment so people don't just stop reading after the accepted answer.

Comment: You should *not* add `-lasan` yourself. You should use the compiler to drive link. The compiler will add the correct libraries when `-fsanitize=address` is present.

Comment: Also confirming this is not the correct way to enable address sanitizer.

Comment: works with gcc 12/debian

Answer (score 171):

You need to add `-fsanitize=address` to compiler flags (both `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`) and linker flags (`LDFLAGS`). You've probably added it to your compiler flags only.

Note that using explicit `-lasan` option has been widely discouraged by ASan developers (e.g. [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/address-sanitizer/SD590XDinfQ/NMUPj_G0BgAJ)) as it misses some other important linker flags. The only recommended way to link is to use `-fsanitize=address`.

As a side note, for more aggressive verification flags check [Asan FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer#faq) (look for "more aggressive diagnostics").

Comment: If I skip the `-lasan`, Im getting `undefined reference to __asan_...`

Comment: @HeinrichStack It's hard to comment without repro. Note that `-fsanitize=address` is equivalent to `-lasan` + some other stuff.

Comment: When using `-Wl,--no-undefined` together with Clang, one must also add `-shared-libasan` to linker flags.
It's also part of official FAQ, but just in case, it's also nice to have this information here.

Comment: @DmitryKochkin Choosing static/shared runtime libraries is a can full of worms (default choice is different between LLVM and GCC, `-static-libasan` does no really work in GCC, shared/static runtimes work differently depending on whether main app is sanitized or not, etc.). In general I suggest to stick with default choice made by your compiler when possible and only switch to `-shared-libasan` in edge cases (which are sanitizing only one library and/or using `-Wl,--no-undefined`). Here's a link to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47022141/2170527) which provides gory details.

Comment: @yugr yes, I said it should be used only with `-Wl,--no-undefined`. The linking in C++ is a can of worms just by itself, you are doomed with this language choice anyway.
And in your another answer you recommend the same for Clang.

Comment: Please emphasize "BOTH" in "to both compiler flags (CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS)" . It does not work when you do it only for one of them!!

Comment: @U.W. "both" was actually meant to mean "both compiler and linker flags" but I agree that this might have been unclear. Fixed.

Comment: @yugr If I add it to the linker `ld`/`ldd` it throws `unrecognized option `-fsanitize=address'` error. Is the linker supposed to be invoked via `clang`?

Comment: @User10482 Yes, you are right, this is a gcc/clang option (`LDFLAGS` variable is typically used for "gcc flags used for linking"). You can find which ld/lld flags it expands to by running gcc/clang with `-v` flag.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you have libasan installed.  For example, in Fedora:

`dnf install libasan libasan-static`

Comment: Indeed this may cause similar error when applying Asan to a single shared library and using `-static-libasan`. Otherwise `gcc` will emit distinct error messages (`libasan_preinit.o: No such file or directory` or `cannot find -lasan`). On Ubuntu `libasan` is installed by default with `gcc`.