# undefined reference to '_asan_init_v4' when compiling

Tags: linux, address-sanitizer

When linking my code compiled with the AddressSanitizer tool, I'm getting many errors of the kind `undefined reference to '_asan_init_v4'`.

```
clang -fPIC -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Wl,-z,defs \
  -shared -Wl,-soname,libqpid-dispatch.so -o libqpid-dispatch.so \
  CMakeFiles/qpid-dispatch.dir/alloc_pool.c.o \
  CMakeFiles/qpid-dispatch.dir/amqp.c.o \
  [...]
  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lpython3.7m -lwebsockets -fsanitize=address
```

Some examples of the errors

```
/nix/store/1zf4cnaaidjajwb4gx4mnkqc5dypkcdy-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-dispatch.dir/http-libwebsockets.c.o: in function `qd_http_server_free':
/home/jdanek/repos/qpid/qpid-dispatch/src/http-libwebsockets.c:824: undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
/nix/store/1zf4cnaaidjajwb4gx4mnkqc5dypkcdy-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: /home/jdanek/repos/qpid/qpid-dispatch/src/http-libwebsockets.c:825: undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
/nix/store/1zf4cnaaidjajwb4gx4mnkqc5dypkcdy-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: /home/jdanek/repos/qpid/qpid-dispatch/src/http-libwebsockets.c:825: undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
/nix/store/1zf4cnaaidjajwb4gx4mnkqc5dypkcdy-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: /home/jdanek/repos/qpid/qpid-dispatch/src/http-libwebsockets.c:825: undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
/nix/store/1zf4cnaaidjajwb4gx4mnkqc5dypkcdy-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: /home/jdanek/repos/qpid/qpid-dispatch/src/http-libwebsockets.c:825: undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_type_mismatch_v1'
/nix/store/1zf4cnaaidjajwb4gx4mnkqc5dypkcdy-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: /home/jdanek/repos/qpid/qpid-dispatch/src/http-libwebsockets.c:825: undefined reference to `__asan_report_load8'
/nix/store/1zf4cnaaidjajwb4gx4mnkqc5dypkcdy-binutils-2.31.1/bin/ld: /home/jdanek/repos/qpid/qpid-dispatch/src/http-libwebsockets.c:825: undefined reference to `__asan_report_load8'
```

**Note:** I am using NixOS 19.09 and Clang 10.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you compile your code (e.g. compile and link line).

Comment: Compile falgs: -Wall ,-g ,Wextra, -Wno-missing-field-initializers,-Wformat=2,-Wpointer-arith,-fno-omit-frame-pointer,-m64,-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE,-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64,-fsanitize=address,-fno-stack-protector,-fno-omit-frame-pointer,-fsanitize-recover=address,-fsanitize=undefined,-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0,-fgnu89-inline

Comment: link flags:-m64,-rdynamic,-fsanitize=address,-fsanitize-recover=address,-fsanitize=undefined,-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0

Comment: Hm, the only idea coming to my mind is that GCC and libasan on your machine are out of synch. Are you using custom GCC? Could you run  `readelf -sW FILENAME | grep asan_init` with `FILENAME` set to one of your object files compiled with `-fsanitize=address` and to `path/to/libasan.so`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use AddressSanitizer in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970758/how-to-use-addresssanitizer-in-gcc)

Comment: This could be manifestation of https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/380. Try removing `-Wl,-z,defs` from your linker command line.

Answer (score 10):

You should be using the compile flag `-fsanitize=address`: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer

Note that `-fsanitize=address` = `-lasan` + some add'l options. And using `-lasan` has been discouraged by ASan developers.

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` isn't enough with GCC.

Comment: @jhasse: Do you have a prooflink for this? Note that you need `-fsanitize=address` both in `CFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS` and in `LDFLAGS` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40215639/2170527).

Comment: actually in my case, adding `-fsanitize=address` makes the whole thing break but removing it makes it work.

Answer (score 2):

(I see @user7610 basically said this in their comment)

You should not use `-z defs`, since it is incompatible with asan.

Source: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html

"When linking shared libraries, the AddressSanitizer run-time is not linked, so -Wl,-z,defs may cause link errors (don’t use it with AddressSanitizer)."

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that this was the problem, but for me, adding `-lasan` to the linker options was enough to get my program to build and run.

Comment: This answer is wrong, adding `-lasan` has been discouraged by Asan developers many times e.g. in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/address-sanitizer/SD590XDinfQ/NMUPj_G0BgAJ). The only supported approach is to use `-fsanitize=address` both in `CFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40215639/2170527)).

Answer (score -1):

Adding `-static-libasan` to linker flags will solves this problem.

Comment: `-static-libasan` is not recommended on GCC though (not very well supported see e.g. [PR 64234](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64234)).