# How to restrict user from using unallocated memory in the malloc implementation at run time in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement `ownmalloc()` by calling original `malloc()` only once at beginning of the code.

Using this memory returned by original `malloc()`, each `ownmalloc()` call from user program uses this memory for allocation.

There are 2 lists maintained allocated and unallocated.

`ownfree()` function removes the allocated memory and adds back to unallocated blocks, orders them and makes the contiguous address blocks as a single block

**I have two questions:**

1. How can I stop user from using unauthorized memory at run time, e.g. user asked 10 blocks and using 13 blocks to write the data.
2. `ownmalloc()` calls a function(say x) which in turn calls original `malloc()` and takes block of memory which will be used by `ownmalloc()` multiple times. How can I make sure that `ownmalloc()` calls this function `x()` only once (during the first call) and at later calls, function call to `x()` shouldn't be done.

I tried it with this approach, but its not working in c

```c
typedef struct mem{
    int sz;
    struct mem *next;
}node;

node *block;
static bool init=false;

void* x(){
    //call to original malloc
}

void* ownmalloc(size){
    if(!init){
        block=x();
        init=true;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to make call to this `ownmalloc()`  `x()` function is being called every time. How do I make it call only once?

Comment: In C, it's impossible to stop programs from using memory other than what they're supposed to use. This is why memory corruption bugs in C are so common.

Comment: Any other alternative or atleast can i display a warning kind of thing using any library

Comment: Use a tool such as AddressSanitizer, which has been included by default in gcc since version 4.8. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970758/how-to-use-addresssanitizer-in-gcc for instructions on use

Comment: Sure, there are lots and lots of absolutely fantastic languages around.

Comment: Is there anything which I can implement in my code which will take care of unauthorized access of memory

Answer (score 0):

Try get the input from the user into a static allocated data structure and check it's size.

if the size is smaller than your allocated memory assign the input and otherwise give an error.
its missing a big point of dynamic memory allocation but i think it should work.