# How to fix &localtime in .txt - C

Tags: c, file

I want to implement a function in my program that sends a .txt to my email with some tasks that i have to do in the day. Here's the code:

```
void txtCreator(){
  /**file.dat and file.txt, respectively**/
  FILE *fp, *fp1;
  /**struct that contain the events**/
  struct evento *display = (struct evento *)malloc(sizeof(struct evento));

  char buffer[48];
  char email_events[] = {"dd_mm.txt"};//filename.txt
  char msg[]={"Nao ha eventos disponiveis para hoje!\n"};
  int count=0;
  time_t rawtime;
  time(&rawtime);
  struct tm timenow = *localtime(&rawtime);
  strftime(buffer, 48, "%d_%m", &timenow);
  fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  fp1 = fopen(email_events, "w");
  if(strcmp(buffer, email_events)!=0){  
    strcpy(email_events, buffer);
    while(fread(display, sizeof(struct evento), 1, fp)==1){
      if (feof(fp) || fp==NULL){
        break;
      }
      else if(display->dia==timenow.tm_mday && display->mes==timenow.tm_mon+1){
        fwrite(display, sizeof(struct evento), 1, fp1);
        fprintf(fp1, "%s", "\n");
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  if(count==0){
    fprintf(fp1, "%s", msg);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  fclose(fp1);
}
```

Everything is working just fine, but there's two problems:

1-

```
strcpy(email_events, buffer);
```

is not working, and:

2-

when i create the .txt file, it shows like that:

**test ¹0(¹€(.v™  ™­  °'¹8¹uguese_Brazil.12**

it shows the event name (test) correctly, but the date is not working.

I've tried a lot of things, but nothing works.

Sorry for the bad english, not my native language.

Comment: `file_name` is never defined, and could you show the definition of `struct evento`?

Comment: `fwrite()` writes the data in the structure to the file as binary data. There's no reason that should be readable as text. If you want to write to the file as text, you need to `fprintf()` each of the structure's elements.

Comment: Is `email_events` supposed to be `"dd_mm.txt"` or is it supposed to contain real numbers? I ask because `strcmp(buffer, email_events)` will never be equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i create the .txt file, it shows like that:
>
> `test ¹0(¹€(.v™ ™­ °'¹8¹uguese_Brazil.12`

Let's address this first: you're not writing text to your `.txt` file. You're writing a struct. It's going to look like garbage.

For example, let's say `display->dia` is 19. This means the number 19 will be written to the file, not the text `19`, the number 19. Read as text, 19 is garbage. 10 is a newline. 65 is `A`.

If your intent is to dump the structs into a file, assuming `struct evento` has no pointers, you're good. In fact you probably shouldn't add a newline, it will interfere with reading the file by the size of the struct.

If your intent is to produce a human readable text file, you need to translate each piece of the struct into text. For example, if you wanted to write the day and month as text...

```
fprintf(fp1, "%d_%d", display->dia, display->mes);
```

I'll assume that going forward.

---

> `strcpy(email_events, buffer);` is not working

At first glance it looks like your `strcpy` is backwards, it's `strcpy(src, dest)` and presumably you want to copy `email_events` into `buffer`: `strcpy(buffer, email_events)`.

Looking further, your code does nothing with either `buffer` nor `email_events` after that. The `strcpy` is pointless.

Going even further, `buffer` is the month and day like `07_19`. `email_events` is always `dd_mm.txt`. Those will never match. `strcmp(buffer, email_events)!=0` will always be true making the `if` check pointless.

I'm not sure what the intent of `buffer` and `email_events` are, but it appears to be trying to create a filename based on the current date?  This can be done much simpler with one better named variable `outfile`.

```
time_t rawtime;
time(&rawtime);
struct tm timenow = *localtime(&rawtime);
char outfile[20];
strftime(outfile, 20, "%d_%m.txt", &timenow);
```

---

Moving along to other problems, you don't check that `fp1` opened.

You do eventually check `fp` but you check it *after* you've already read from a possibly null file pointer. If you're [compiling with an address sanitizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40215639/14660) (which you should) it will cause an error. Causing an error when using a null pointer is good, it will solve many a mystery memory problem for you.

It's much easier and robust and address sanitizer friendly to check immediately. We can also do a better job naming them to avoid confusing the input from the output: `in` and `out`.

```
FILE *in = fopen(file_name, "rb");
if( in == NULL ) {
    perror(file_name);
    exit(1);
}
```

And since you're reading binary with `rb` you should be writing binary you should be using `wb`. This only matters on Windows, but might as well be consistent.

```
FILE *out = fopen(outfile, "wb");
if( out == NULL ) {
    perror(outfile);
    exit(1);
}
```

There's no need to check `feof(fp)`, `while(fread(display, sizeof(struct evento), 1, fp)==1)` will already exit the loop at end of file when it fails to read. In general, explicitly checking for the end of file leads to subtle problems.

The read/write loop is now much simpler.

```
while(fread(display, sizeof(struct evento), 1, in)==1){
    if(display->dia==timenow.tm_mday && display->mes==timenow.tm_mon+1) {
        fprintf(out, "%d_%d\n", display->dia, display->mes);
        count++;
    }
}
```

---

Putting it all together...

```
void txtCreator(){
    const char *no_events_found_msg = "Nao ha eventos disponiveis para hoje!\n";
    
    // No need to cast the result of malloc, it just invites mistakes.
    struct evento *display = malloc(sizeof(struct evento));
        
    // Generate the output filename directly, no strcmp and strcpy necessary.
    time_t rawtime;
    time(&rawtime);
    struct tm timenow = *localtime(&rawtime);
    char outfile[20];
    strftime(outfile, 48, "%d_%m.txt", &timenow);

    // Immediatetly make sure the files are open and error immediately.
    FILE *in = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if( in == NULL ) {
        perror(file_name);
        exit(1);
    }
  
    FILE *out = fopen(outfile, "wb");
    if( out == NULL ) {
        perror(outfile);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Now that we know the files are open, reading and writing is much simpler.
    int count=0;
    while(fread(display, sizeof(struct evento), 1, in)==1){
        if(display->dia==timenow.tm_mday && display->mes==timenow.tm_mon+1) {
            fprintf(out, "%d_%d\n", display->dia, display->mes);
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    if(count==0){
        fprintf(out, "%s", no_events_found_msg);
    }
    
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
}
```

Note that I've used a style which declares variables in place. This makes the code easier to read, limits the scope of each variable, and it avoids declaring variables which you never use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are meaning to copy `email_events` into your `buffer` (since you assigned a static string), your `strcpy` parameters are backwards.

Below is the declaration of `strcpy`

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

You probably meant:

```
strcpy(buffer, email_events);
```

Comment: Nothing is done with `buffer` after that, I think it's more than this.