# clang vs gcc behavioral difference with AddressSanitizer

Tags: gcc, memory-leaks, clang, address-sanitizer

I have a sample code with memory leaks. Though clang displays the leak correctly, I am unable to achieve the same with gcc. gcc version I am using is 4.8.5-39

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void *p;
int main() {
  p = malloc(7);
  p = 0; // The memory is leaked here.
  return 0;
}
```

CLANG:

```
clang -fsanitize=address -g memory-leak.c ; ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out

=================================================================
==15543==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 7 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x465289 in __interceptor_malloc (/u/optest/a.out+0x465289)
    #1 0x47b549 in main /u/optest/memory-leak.c:4
    #2 0x7f773fe14544 in __libc_start_main /usr/src/debug/glibc-2.17-c758a686/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:266

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 7 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

GCC:

```
gcc -fsanitize=address -g memory-leak.c ; ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out
```

I need to use gcc. Can someone help me understand why gcc isn't behaving like clang and what should I do to make it work.

Comment: Try again with a less ancient version of gcc, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone help me understand why gcc isn't behaving like clang

Gcc-4.8 [was released on March 22, 2013](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/).

The patch to support `-fsanitize=leak` [was sent on Nov. 15, 2013](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/291656/), and is likely not backported into the 4.8 release.

GCC-8.3 has no trouble detecting this leak:

```
$ gcc -g -fsanitize=address memory-leak.c && ./a.out

=================================================================
==166614==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 7 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fcaf3dc5330 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0xe9330)
    #1 0x55d297afc162 in main /tmp/memory-leak.c:4
    #2 0x7fcaf394052a in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 7 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Answer (score 0):

This item in [Asan's FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer#faq) is relevant:

```
Q: Why didn't ASan report an obviously invalid
   memory access in my code?

A1: If your errors is too obvious, compiler might have
    already optimized it out by the time Asan runs.
```

Comment: But the same ASan detects the memory leak when used with clang

Comment: @VinodiniNatrajan Implementation of Clang's Asan is completely different from GCC so don't expect 100% match between them. In general they would detect more or less the same errors but this is not guaranteed, especially in corner cases like this one which are very sensitive to other optization passes.