# C++ segfault, reproducible example

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, segmentation-fault, gdb

Reposting with full code, as suggested from others. Just updated the main function with hard coded arguments that causes segmentation fault.

Changing the **width** and **height** to something else lets the program run fine, for example 500 and 433 respectively.

Main file:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include "sierpinski.h"

Triangle::Triangle() {
  this->pixels = nullptr;
  this->top = Coordinate();
  this->left = Coordinate();
  this->right = Coordinate();
  this->fg_color = 0;
  this->area = 0.0;
}

Triangle::Triangle(uint32_t* pixels, Coordinate top, Coordinate left, Coordinate right, uint32_t fg_color) {
  this->pixels = pixels;
  this->top = top;
  this->left = left;
  this->right = right;
  this->fg_color = fg_color;
  this->area = calculateArea(top, left, right);
}

void Triangle::DrawLines(Coordinate top, Coordinate left, Coordinate right) {
  int width = getWidth(this->left, this->right);
  //left to top
  std::vector<Coordinate> line = left.Bresenham(top);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++) {
    this->pixels[width * line[i].getY() + line[i].getX()] = this->fg_color;
  }
  line.clear();
  // left to right
  line = left.Bresenham(right);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++) {
    this->pixels[width * line[i].getY() + line[i].getX()] = this->fg_color;
  }
  line.clear();
  // top to right
  line = top.Bresenham(right);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++) {
    this->pixels[width * line[i].getY() + line[i].getX()] = this->fg_color;
  }
}

void Triangle::Sierpinski(Coordinate top, Coordinate left, Coordinate right, const double min_area) {
  if (calculateArea(top, left, right) < min_area) {
    return;
  }
  DrawLines(top, left, right);

  Triangle triangle(this->pixels, top, left, right, this->fg_color);

  Sierpinski(top, top.Midpoint(left), top.Midpoint(right), min_area);
  Sierpinski(top.Midpoint(left), left, left.Midpoint(right), min_area);
  Sierpinski(top.Midpoint(right), left.Midpoint(right), right, min_area);
}

uint32_t* Triangle::getPixels() {
  return this->pixels;
}

uint32_t Triangle::getFg_color() {
  return this->fg_color;
}

double Triangle::getArea() {
  return this->area;
}

double Triangle::getWidth(Coordinate left, Coordinate right) {
  return left.distance(right);
}

double Triangle::calculateArea(Coordinate top, Coordinate left, Coordinate right) {
  return std::abs(top.getX() * (left.getY() - right.getY()) + left.getX() * (right.getY() - top.getY()) + right.getX() * (top.getY() - left.getY())) / 2.0;
}

Coordinate::Coordinate() {
  this->x = 0;
  this->y = 0;
}

Coordinate::Coordinate(int x, int y) {
  this->x = x;
  this->y = y;
}

Coordinate::Coordinate(const Coordinate &other) {
  this->x = other.x;
  this->y = other.y;
}

int Coordinate::getX() {
  return this->x;
}

int Coordinate::getY() {
  return this->y;
}

double Coordinate::distance(Coordinate other) {
  return std::sqrt(std::pow((this->x - other.x), 2) + std::pow((this->y - other.y), 2));
}

Coordinate Coordinate::Midpoint(Coordinate other) {
  double midX = (this->x + other.getX()) / 2;
  double midY = (this->y + other.getY()) / 2;
  return Coordinate(midX, midY);
}

int Coordinate::gcd(int a, int b) {
  if (b == 0)
    return a;
  return gcd(b, a%b);
}

std::vector<Coordinate> Coordinate::Bresenham(Coordinate other) {
  int x1 = this->x, y1 = this->y;
  int const x2 = other.x, y2 = other.y;
  std::vector<Coordinate> points;

  int delta_x(x2 - x1);
  signed char const ix((delta_x > 0) - (delta_x < 0));
  delta_x = std::abs(delta_x) << 1;

  int delta_y(y2 - y1);
  signed char const iy((delta_y > 0) - (delta_y < 0));
  delta_y = std::abs(delta_y) << 1;

  Coordinate newPoint1(x1, y1);
  points.push_back(newPoint1);

  if (delta_x >= delta_y) {
    int error(delta_y - (delta_x >> 1));
      while (x1 != x2) {
        if ((error > 0) || (!error && (ix > 0))) {
          error -= delta_x;
          y1 += iy;
        }
        error += delta_y;
        x1 += ix;

        Coordinate newPoint2(x1, y1);
        points.push_back(newPoint2);
     }
  } else {
      int error(delta_x - (delta_y >> 1));

      while (y1 != y2) {
        if ((error > 0) || (!error && (iy > 0))) {
          error -= delta_y;
          x1 += ix;
        }
        error += delta_x;
        y1 += iy;

        Coordinate newPoint3(x1, y1);
        points.push_back(newPoint3);
      }
  }
  return points;
}

int main() {
  int width = 55;
  int height = 40;
  uint32_t bg_color = 4095617261;
  uint32_t fg_color = 2988200782;
  double min_area = 1.08;

  std::vector<uint32_t> pixels(width * height, bg_color);
  Coordinate top, left, right;
  top = Coordinate(width / 2, 0);
  left = Coordinate(0, height);
  right = Coordinate(width, height);

  Triangle triangle = Triangle(pixels.data(), top, left, right, fg_color);
  triangle.Sierpinski(top, left, right, min_area);
  std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(pixels.data()), width * height * 4);
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef SIERPINSKI_H
#define SIERPINSKI_H
#include <vector>

class Coordinate {
 public:
    Coordinate();
    Coordinate(int x, int y);
    Coordinate(const Coordinate &other);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    double distance(Coordinate);
    Coordinate Midpoint(Coordinate other);
    int gcd(int a, int b);
    std::vector<Coordinate> Bresenham(Coordinate other);
    int countPoints(Coordinate other);
    std::vector<Coordinate> getPoints(Coordinate other);
 private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

class Triangle {
 public:
    Triangle();
    Triangle(uint32_t* pixels, Coordinate top, Coordinate left, Coordinate right, uint32_t fg_color);
    void DrawLines(Coordinate top, Coordinate left, Coordinate right);
    void Draw(double min_area);
    void Sierpinski(Coordinate top, Coordinate left, Coordinate right, double min_area);
    double calculateArea(Coordinate top, Coordinate left, Coordinate right);
    uint32_t* getPixels();
    uint32_t getFg_color();
    double getArea();
    Coordinate top, left, right;
    double getWidth(Coordinate left, Coordinate right);
 private:
    uint32_t* pixels;
    uint32_t fg_color;
    double area;
};

#endif
```

After using gdb, it seemed the error was occuring in my Bresenham function at the line:

```
points.push_back(newPoint3);
```

But other users stated that seg fault may not be occurring exactly where gdb says it is. If anyone can provide further insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Recommendation: replace the command line arguments with values that you know will expose the bug. It's really annoying when someone answers the question with a solution based on a different bug found with different inputs.

Comment: Sidenote: sierpinski.h uses `uint32_t` but does not include `<cstdint>`. It's not an error at the moment because of the include order of sierpinski.h in main.cpp, but this could come back to bite you later.

Comment: Thanks for the sidenote, also I included a case in my original post that exposes the bug right? I'm confused about your first comment.

Comment: I see the inputs, but why have inputs at all? Hard code them into the program so that there is no room for error.

Comment: Oh I got it, thanks for the tip. I didn't think of doing that, that would make it easier for people.

Comment: Also unrelated: There is no need for a copy constructor in `Coordinate`.  There's noting in it that the default copy constructor can't handle. See the [Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Shouldn't change a thing WRT the bug.

Answer (score 3):

The crash happens here:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7b12c46 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7e5e059 in operator new(unsigned long) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00000000004035ac in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Coordinate>::allocate (this=0x7fffffffd3f0, __n=2) at /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:114
#3  0x000000000040335b in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Coordinate> >::allocate (__a=..., __n=2) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:444
#4  0x0000000000402fe2 in std::_Vector_base<Coordinate, std::allocator<Coordinate> >::_M_allocate (this=0x7fffffffd3f0, __n=2) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:343
#5  0x00000000004028be in std::vector<Coordinate, std::allocator<Coordinate> >::_M_realloc_insert<Coordinate const&> (this=0x7fffffffd3f0, __position={x = 0, y = 0}, __args#0=...) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:440
#6  0x00000000004024a0 in std::vector<Coordinate, std::allocator<Coordinate> >::push_back (this=0x7fffffffd3f0, __x=...) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1195
#7  0x0000000000401f48 in Coordinate::Bresenham (this=0x7fffffffd4c8, other=...) at t.cc:205
#8  0x0000000000401610 in Triangle::DrawLines (this=0x7fffffffd580, top=..., left=..., right=...) at t.cc:86
#9  0x0000000000401823 in Triangle::Sierpinski (this=0x7fffffffd580, top=..., left=..., right=..., min_area=1.0800000000000001) at t.cc:96
#10 0x0000000000402154 in main () at t.cc:225
```

*Any* time you have a crash in `malloc`, you should immediately suspect heap corruption.

Here is what [address sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (just add `-fsanitize=address` to your compile and link command lines) says:

```
=================================================================
==5470==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x625000002360 at pc 0x000000401e84 bp 0x7fffffffcdb0 sp 0x7fffffffcda0
WRITE of size 4 at 0x625000002360 thread T0
    #0 0x401e83 in Triangle::DrawLines(Coordinate, Coordinate, Coordinate) /tmp/t.cc:76
    #1 0x4028c5 in Triangle::Sierpinski(Coordinate, Coordinate, Coordinate, double) /tmp/t.cc:96
    #2 0x4043df in main /tmp/t.cc:225
    #3 0x7ffff707ef32 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x23f32)
    #4 0x40126d in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x40126d)

0x625000002360 is located 0 bytes to the right of 8800-byte region [0x625000000100,0x625000002360)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7ffff768a9d7 in operator new(unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.5+0x10f9d7)
    #1 0x406f82 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:114
    #2 0x406e67 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<unsigned int> >::allocate(std::allocator<unsigned int>&, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:444
    #3 0x406b8f in std::_Vector_base<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:343
    #4 0x40663e in std::_Vector_base<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:358
    #5 0x405a5c in std::_Vector_base<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<unsigned int> const&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:302
    #6 0x404bf0 in std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::vector(unsigned long, unsigned int const&, std::allocator<unsigned int> const&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:521
    #7 0x403faa in main /tmp/t.cc:218
    #8 0x7ffff707ef32 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x23f32)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow /tmp/t.cc:76 in Triangle::DrawLines(Coordinate, Coordinate, Coordinate)
```

So indeed you have heap corruption (overflow of allocated heap buffer).

Hopefully this is enough info for you to find a logic bug in your program.

P.S.

It looks like you are allocating a rectangle of `height` * `width` pixels, then try to draw a line from the `height * width`s pixel. You likely have an off-by-one bug -- valid pixel *indices* are in the range `[0 .. width-1] * [0 .. height-1]`.

When I reserve `(width+1) * (height+1)` space in the vector, the problem goes away.

Comment: Asan is a good choice. To enable it ensure `CXXFLAGS` includes `-fsanitize=address`. Also see [How to use AddressSanitizer in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37970758/608639)