# How does code know that it is compiled or running with AddressSanitizer or ThreadSanitizer?

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer, thread-sanitizer

I would like for my C++ program to be able to print if it was compiled with AddressSanitizer or ThreadSanitizer. The solution proposed in [AddressSanitizer: How could we know that object file/executable in C is compiled with AddressSanitizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59818881/addresssanitizer-how-could-we-know-that-object-file-executable-in-c-is-compiled) will not work because I do not want the program to have to open its own object code and explore itself that way. Is there a `#define` that it can check for?  I can add my own, but I don't want to add one if one already exists.

Comment: When you compile with AddressSanitizer you can also define `-DASAN=1`, or ThreadSanitizer `-DTSAN=1`.  I see that `-fsanitize=address` already supplied pre-define `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` but I don't know if that's long term reliable.  I don't see ThreadSanitizer having a pre-define.

Comment: It does. I will delete this. Thanks. I wonder why search did not turn that up.