# Is there way to verify my program has no memory leaks?

Tags: c, debugging, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I wish to determine if the following program (an implementation of finding the maximum sub-array) leaks memory. Is there a general way to determine this? Such as using some feature of a debugger? What are general strategies?

```
struct Interval {
   int max_left;
   int max_right;
   int sum;
};

struct Interval * max_crossing_subarray(int A[], int low, int mid, int high) {
    struct Interval * crossing = malloc(sizeof(struct Interval));

    int left_sum = INT_MIN;
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = mid; i >= low; --i) {
        sum = sum + A[i];
        if(sum > left_sum) {
            left_sum = sum;
            crossing->max_left = i;
        }
    }

    int right_sum = INT_MIN;
    sum = 0;

    for(int j = mid+1; j <= high; ++j) {
        sum = sum + A[j];
        if(sum > right_sum) {
            right_sum = sum;
            crossing->max_right = j;
        }
    }

    crossing->sum = left_sum + right_sum;

    return crossing;
}

struct Interval * max_subarray(int A[], int low, int high) {
    if(high == low) {
        struct Interval * base = malloc(sizeof(struct Interval));
        *base = (struct Interval) { low, high, A[low] };
        return base;
    } else {
        int mid = floor((low+high)/2);
        struct Interval * left = malloc(sizeof(struct Interval));
        struct Interval * right = malloc(sizeof(struct Interval));
        left = max_subarray(A, low, mid);
        right = max_subarray(A, mid+1, high);
        struct Interval * cross = max_crossing_subarray(A, low, mid, high);
        if(left->sum >= right->sum & right->sum >= cross->sum) {
            free(right);
            free(cross);
            return left;
        } else if(right->sum >= left->sum & right->sum >= cross-> sum) {
            free(left);
            free(cross);
            return right;
        } else {
            free(left);
            free(right);
            return cross;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = {-10, 7, -5, -3, 40, 4, -1, 8, -3, -1, -5, 20, 7};
    struct Interval * result = max_subarray(A, 0, 12);

    printf("left: %i, right: %i, sum: %i\n", result->max_left, result->max_right, result->sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Due to the recursive nature of the program it's quite difficult to follow (at least for me). I think I've plugged everything but I'd like to find a methodology for being sure.

**Edit**: *The software suggested in the selected answer allowed me to find all my leaks and as pointed out in the comment there was no reason to allocate left and right, below is the memory leak free code.*

```
struct Interval {
   int max_left;
   int max_right;
   int sum;
};

struct Interval * max_crossing_subarray(int A[], int low, int mid, int high) {
    struct Interval * crossing = malloc(sizeof(struct Interval));

    int left_sum = INT_MIN;
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = mid; i >= low; --i) {
        sum = sum + A[i];
        if(sum > left_sum) {
            left_sum = sum;
            crossing->max_left = i;
        }
    }

    int right_sum = INT_MIN;
    sum = 0;

    for(int j = mid+1; j <= high; ++j) {
        sum = sum + A[j];
        if(sum > right_sum) {
            right_sum = sum;
            crossing->max_right = j;
        }
    }

    crossing->sum = left_sum + right_sum;

    return crossing;
}

struct Interval * max_subarray(int A[], int low, int high) {
    if(high == low) {
        struct Interval * base = malloc(sizeof(struct Interval));
        *base = (struct Interval) { low, high, A[low] };
        return base;
    } else {
        int mid = floor((low+high)/2);
        struct Interval * left = max_subarray(A, low, mid);
        struct Interval * right = max_subarray(A, mid+1, high);
        struct Interval * cross = max_crossing_subarray(A, low, mid, high);
        if(left->sum >= right->sum & right->sum >= cross->sum) {
            free(right);
            free(cross);
            return left;
        } else if(right->sum >= left->sum & right->sum >= cross-> sum) {
            free(left);
            free(cross);
            return right;
        } else {
            free(left);
            free(right);
            return cross;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = {-10, 7, -5, -3, 40, 4, -1, 8, -3, -1, -5, 20, 7};
    struct Interval * result = max_subarray(A, 0, 13-1);

    printf("left: %i, right: %i, sum: %i\n", result->max_left, result->max_right, result->sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my eyes it leaks almost everything it allocates. You allocate for `left` and `right` and then throw the allocations away by assigning something else to the variables immediately after. So that memory is lost and after that no idea what the `free`s actually free.

Comment: Ivor Denham-Dyson,  Curious, why `floor((low+high)/2);` instead of `(low+high)/2;`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ```(low+high)/2``` is not guaranteed to return an integer although  I don't think the implicit cast would cause a problem.

Comment: IvorDenham-Dyson, Thanks for the info.  With `int low` and `int high`, `(low+high)/2` returns an `int`.  There is no cast.  The quotient's fraction is discarded - round towards zero.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Agreed, I have included it as I'm translating pseudo code but yes I imagine its unnecessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org/).  It's a memory debugging tool for Linux and other UNIX-like systems that finds memory leaks as well as invalid memory accesses.

When I run this code through valgrind, it outputs the following:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ valgrind ./x1
==3406== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3406== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3406== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3406== Command: ./x1
==3406== 
left: 4, right: 12, sum: 69
==3406== 
==3406== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3406==     in use at exit: 300 bytes in 25 blocks
==3406==   total heap usage: 49 allocs, 24 frees, 588 bytes allocated
==3406== 
==3406== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3406==    definitely lost: 300 bytes in 25 blocks
==3406==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3406==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3406==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3406==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3406== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3406== 
==3406== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3406== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So you have some leaks.  Now let's pass the `--leak-check=full` option to see where exactly those leaks are:

```
==11531== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11531== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11531== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11531== Command: ./x1
==11531== 
left: 4, right: 12, sum: 69
==11531== 
==11531== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11531==     in use at exit: 300 bytes in 25 blocks
==11531==   total heap usage: 49 allocs, 24 frees, 588 bytes allocated
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 10 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 11 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 12 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 13 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 14 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 15 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 16 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 17 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 18 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 19 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 20 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 21 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 22 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 23 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007A8: max_subarray (x1.c:49)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 24 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x4007B6: max_subarray (x1.c:50)
==11531==    by 0x4007CE: max_subarray (x1.c:51)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x4007E9: max_subarray (x1.c:52)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 25 of 25
==11531==    at 0x4C29EA3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==11531==    by 0x40065B: max_crossing_subarray (x1.c:13)
==11531==    by 0x400802: max_subarray (x1.c:53)
==11531==    by 0x400931: main (x1.c:73)
==11531== 
==11531== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11531==    definitely lost: 300 bytes in 25 blocks
==11531==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11531==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11531==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11531==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11531== 
==11531== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11531== ERROR SUMMARY: 25 errors from 25 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Most of these leaks are coming from these two lines:

```
    struct Interval * left = malloc(sizeof(struct Interval));
    struct Interval * right = malloc(sizeof(struct Interval));
```

And if we look at the next two lines it's apparent why:

```
    left = max_subarray(A, low, mid);
    right = max_subarray(A, mid+1, high);
```

So right after you assign the address of allocated memory to these pointers you overwrite those addresses with other values, causing a leak.  This can be fixed by getting rid of the `malloc` calls and initializing with the result of the function calls:

```
    struct Interval * left = max_subarray(A, low, mid);
    struct Interval * right = max_subarray(A, mid+1, high);
```

The last one is in `max_crossing_subarray`

```
struct Interval * crossing = malloc(sizeof(struct Interval));
```

This pointer is returned from the function, so we need to see where the missing `free` is.  After some looking around, we see that it is called from `max_subarray`, which eventually returns it to `main` as `result`:

```
struct Interval * result = max_subarray(A, 0, 13-1);

printf("left: %i, right: %i, sum: %i\n", result->max_left, result->max_right, result->sum);

return 0;
```

But as you can see, there's no call to `free` here, so let's add it:

```
struct Interval * result = max_subarray(A, 0, 13-1);

printf("left: %i, right: %i, sum: %i\n", result->max_left, result->max_right, result->sum);

free(result);
return 0;
```

Now after making those fixes we'll run through valgrind again:

```
==11736== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11736== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11736== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11736== Command: ./x1
==11736== 
left: 4, right: 12, sum: 69
==11736== 
==11736== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11736==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11736==   total heap usage: 25 allocs, 25 frees, 300 bytes allocated
==11736== 
==11736== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11736== 
==11736== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11736== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

And the leaks are gone.

Comment: This is so useful. Thank you

Comment: Valgrind is not for Linux only. It is available for Solaris, Android and most of all macOS too.

Answer (score 2):

In general you cannot prove your program correctness unless you restrict the language to a sublanguage (like misra) with less features. In general the problem is undecidable.

But you can use software like lint for static check of math patterns, or valgrind for dynamic check, or languages like Coq in which the programs are proofs and they use the Hoare logic to make statements about your code.  For example, using Hoare logic, it is proved that the kernel of Windows never segment faults.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the already mentioned detectors, including the most prominent [valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org/), You can use the [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) tool, which got [LeakSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer) integrated and is implemented in `GCC` since version 4.8 and `Clang` since version 3.1.

The respecitive compiler flags are `-fsanitize=address` and `-fsanitize=leak`.

Furthermore, you can use [MemorySanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizer), for read attempts at uninitialized data.

---

For `gcc` you can find all relevant flags [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html).

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html

[How to use AddressSanitizer with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970758/how-to-use-addresssanitizer-with-gcc)

Answer (score 0):

Every allocated by malloc structure must be released by free in all cases of your program.
So, in all cases you returning one instance of Interval. You must free it in main block.
Or you can use smart pointers/allocators.
Also you can implement operator = for Interval, and use instances instead of pointers.
For fast assigning return value you can use std::swap

```
Intreval & operator=(Intreval && a)
{
    std::swap(a.max_left,max_left);
    std::swap(a.max_rignt,max_rignt);
    std::swap(a.sum,sum);
    return *this;
}
```

Eventually, don't use malloc if you are not shure.

Comment: Thanks Anton, this question is in respect to C not C++ but maybe someone will find it helpful.

Comment: In this case only free in main block can help. :-)
I didn't pay attention to the tag "c", sorry.