# How to stop using AddressSanitizer?

Tags: c, gcc, address-sanitizer

I am going to take a hit here because I am using tools I don't fully understand and haven't taken the time to do so. I just want to remove unnecessary steps / dependencies from my work quickly at this point.

I was using [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) to find the cause of segfaults and other issues in my C code during development. I did this by adding `-fsanitize=address` to my list of `CFLAGS` in a Makefile.

Now, having fixed all such issues, if I remove this flag from my compilation, I can no longer compile my code, and get many errors much like those described in this question...

[How to use AddressSanitizer with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970758/how-to-use-addresssanitizer-with-gcc)

> ~/xxx/util.c:20: undefined reference to `__asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return' /usr/bin/ld: ~/xxx/util.c:20: undefined reference to` __asan_stack_malloc_2'
> usr/bin/ld: /xxx/util.c:23: undefined reference to `__asan_report_store8' /usr/bin/ld: /xxx/util.c:40: undefined reference to` __asan_report_load8' /usr/bin/ld:
> /xxx/util.c:45: undefined reference
> to `__asan_report_load8' /usr/bin/ld:
> And so on.

The difference is I just want to compile my code normally. In that question, they suggest adding a flag `-lasan` to link/compile step. That doesn't seem like it will help me to stop using `-fsanitize`, though I could be wrong. Obviously something is wrong in the linking step here. It feels like I have included a dependency that I forgot about somewhere, but I don't recall doing that.

What am I missing? Probably something obvious. Also, let me know if I need to give more info about my compilation step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is simple: for it to work, `-fsanitize=address` must be present in *both* compilation *and* linking command lines. To disable it, it must not be used in either.

You must have old `.o` object files in your build directory. One solution would be to use `make clean` to remove the intermediate or target files.

If you do not have the `clean` target, now would be good time to write it... or use something like `find -name '*.o' -delete` or `rm **/*.o` if fortunate enough to use ZSH.

Comment: It sounds to me that it's time for Brian to start using a tool such as `cmake` which 99.999% of the time automatically takes care of issues like these (i.e. `cmake` copies the flags to both places as required, it rebuilds the targets if/when necessary, and it gives you a free `clean` target...)

Answer (score 4):

> I just want to compile my code normally

Removing the `-fsanitize=...` flag *should* do exactly that.

Your problem most likely stems from not rebuilding all the objects (when you update `Makefile`, `make` doesn't automatically know to rebuild everything).

Running `make clean; make` or `find . -name '*.o' | xargs rm; make` should do the trick.

Comment: note that it is possible to set up the Makefile so that it does rebuild everything when the Makefile changes  (OP obviously has not done that)